# Unable to find the effective build configuration in target, git checkout crashes with Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, git

Intermittently when entering *git checkout (any branch)* in Terminal, Xcode 7.3 is crashing for me:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7D175
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-10145/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/ProjectModel/DataModel/Targets/PBXTarget.m:2170
Details:  Unable to find the effective build configuration in target <PBXNativeTarget:0x7f849cf9b440:824A9DD41724E16400C9BD79:name='Redacted'> named "Debug".
Object:   <PBXNativeTarget: 0x7f849cf9b440>
Method:   -cachedMacroExpansionScopeForBuildParameters:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8492e13730>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[PBXTarget cachedMacroExpansionScopeForBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   __110+[XCCodeSignContext codesignParameterSnapshotWithMacroExpansionScope:emitWarnings:certificateUtilities:error:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
  5   __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  6   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
  7   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
  8   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
  9   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 10   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 11   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 12   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 13   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 14   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 15   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 16   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18  0x0000000102c3a39b (in Xcode)
 19   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

I wasn't experiencing this with Xcode 7.2. Is this a new problem with Xcode 7.3 or something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: There appears to be a number of issues with 7.3; you might want to roll-back to 7.2 until 7.3.1 is released.  Alternatively use the command line or SourceTree.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I always recommend quitting Xcode before doing something with `git` behind Xcode's back. Basically you are suddenly changing files that are under Xcode's control while it is running, and it doesn't like that. It only takes a moment to quit Xcode, do your twiddling in Terminal, and launch Xcode again; so do that and you'll be fine. Either that, or use the commands *in* Xcode so that it knows what to expect. But don't do `git` in the Terminal on the project that Xcode has open at that moment.

Comment: It's not intended as a workaround. Switching branches with the project open Xcode was _never_ a good idea.

Comment: Ok, but I would have thought that if Xcode wants exclusive access to files, or needs exclusive access to operate properly, then it would have a responsibility to put a lock on them? I mean, from a UX perspective, it violates the Principle of Least Astonishment if actions in one application crash another

Comment: I guess I've been doing this so long that Xcode crashing when breathed on _is_ the Principle of Least Astonishment for me.